# vba code for placing multiple worksheets after a named worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code that copies a template workheet multiple times creating a number of worksheets dependant on a dynmanic list of required tab names. The tabs are created after the last of the current tabs in the workbook however I would like them to be inserted after the template worksheet. Is there a simple vba code to do this?

Thanks

Anna

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim nTimes As Long
    nTimes = 3
    For i = 1 To nTimes
        Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets("Template")
    Next i
End Sub
```